# transpose UDF in pyspark

Tags: scala, pyspark

How to create transpose udf in pyspark.
I have code in scala language, can anyone convert into pyspark.

```
def transposeUDF_2(transDF: DataFrame, transBy: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {
      val (cols, types) = transDF.dtypes.filter{ case (c, _) => !transBy.contains(c)}.unzip
      val kvs = explode(array(
        cols.map(c => struct(lit(c).alias("name"), col(c).alias("value"))): _*
      ))
      val byExprs = transBy.map(col(_))
      transDF
        .select(byExprs :+ kvs.alias("_kvs"): _*)
        .select(byExprs ++ Seq(col("_kvs.name"), col("_kvs.value")): _*)
    }
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Why do you want to convert your working `scala` code into equivalent `pyspark` ? What's the use case?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

```
def transposeUDF_2(df, by):

    # Filter dtypes and split into column names and type description
    cols, dtypes = zip(*((c, t) for (c, t) in df.dtypes if c not in by))
    # Spark SQL supports only homogeneous columns
    assert len(set(dtypes)) == 1, "All columns have to be of the same type"

    # Create and explode an array of (column_name, column_value) structs
    kvs = explode(array([
      struct(lit(c).alias("name"), col(c).alias("value")) for c in cols
    ])).alias("kvs")

    return df.select(by + [kvs]).select(by + ["kvs.name", "kvs.value"])

transpose_df1_2 = transposeUDF_2(df, ["col1","col2"])
```